# Exclude Logback logging

Tags: java, log4j, logback

My log4j.properties file is not used but configured correctly (VM args: -Dlog4j.debug=true) Instead it seems to me, that one required lib (via ivy) is using logback and now some logback default layout pattern is used.

How can I prevent, that my app uses logback instead of log4j? Any ideas? Or how can I use sth. like -Dlog4j.debug=true for logback?

At the moment I just exclude the logback lib in one loaded ivy lib with logback dependency. Is there a better way?

Comment: Does your app use slf4j and you expected log4j to be used as the implementation but logback is getting used at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Remove any `logback-classic.jar` and  `logback-core.jar` from your classpath (files may contain version numbers). If you have dependencies in Maven, exclude logback ([example for log4j](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings)).

Answer (score 0):

```
<exclude org="log4j"/>
<exclude org="logback-classic"/>
<exclude org="logback-core"/>
```

if these dependencies are coming with another dependency then you need to exclude like below

```
 <dependency org="...." name=".." rev="..." conf="...">
      <exclude org="logback-classic"/>
      <exclude org="logback-core"/>
</dependency>
```